# Delegate user administration to a limited set of users

Tags: 7, users, authentication-authorization

We are currently using the excellent `domain` module (allows segmenting users by domain) in and the `user_import` module (allows uploading users via CSV) in Drupal 7.

We've got a new requirement where we want certain authorised users to be able to perform CSV uploads and edit user details for other users within their `domain`, but limited to no other admin function within the site (or other user details).

Without re-implementing each function (edit users, upload CSV, etc) in a new module (my fallback plan), is this possible within the Drupal permission / authorisation framework?

My gut feeling and exploration so far is no, it isn't. But I am no Drupal expert...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was never able to find a workaround for this. I ended up replicating the UI outside of the admin panel and reused a collection of the import functions (I also abandoned the users making "manual" edits.)